# I installed GRUB bootloader on the Win SSD, should I be worried? Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ssd, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu yesterday on my Notebook's SSD. Windows 8.1 preinstalled on the other (m.2) SSD.

I'm not really experienced with this stuff, sorry.

I installed the GRUB(?) boot loader onto the SSD with windows, because the first time I choose to install the bootloader onto the SSD where I was installing Ubuntu it didn't boot Ubuntu, just Windows. So I thought what I was doing is wrong, but my friend told me today...

...that I should have installed the bootloader onto the Ubuntu SSD and just that I needed to change the boot order. He said now that I installed the bootloader on the windows SSD, if I ever want to get rid of Ubuntu, I will have to restore the Windows boot loader and that's kind of tricky.

Should I be worried or something like that? Can I somehow change this now so it won't make me problems later (if I for whatever reason want to delete ubuntu)?

Comment: If it is Windows pre-installed you have UEFI. And with UEFI you should be able to just choose Windows in UEFI or one time boot key. Actual issue with most Windows 8 systems it Windows will keep resetting itself to first. But I do prefer each drive have the boot loader for the install on the same drive. But if UEFI you have to add an efi partition which should be near beginning of drive. Post this above `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't worry because:

1. You can get rid of Ubuntu without touching GRUB
2. You can boot your Windows 8.1 recovery CD and it'll automatically get rid of grub (and Ubuntu!  Be careful!)
3. If you have UEFI, it's even less of a problem: just delete some files...

Changing boot stuff after it's been installed is always trickier then just deleting things.  So if in a half a year or so you want to delete Windows 8.1 just open a new question and you'll find tons of people wanting to help you!  ;-)

P.S. We'll also help you to delete Ubuntu, *but* I deleted Windows about a year ago to make space for more Ubuntu and deleted the Windows 10 preview about 2 weeks ago, so it's not inconceivable you will too!